# Reading program return value in shell using python

Tags: python, bash, return-value

From the python document http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

If I type the following in python

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

I will get a 0.

If I type the following in python,

```
>>> subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
```

I will get a 1. However, if I type

```
>>> subprocess.call("exit 1")
```

It will show me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why does this happen?

Second question, if `ls` crashes, will I get a non-zero return value by using the following command?

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exit` is a shell routine, not a real program. You get an error because the call can not find a program named `exit`. If you don't set the `shell` argument to `True` this makes no sense to executing it.

To answer your second question, yes you will get an non-zero returning value. Try listing a directory in which you don't have read rights.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if `shell=True` the command will be executed through a shell. You can pass a command line like in a shell. If you omit that param, the first param is threatened as a file name, the file name of the command. and there is no command `'exit 1'`

Here comes another example using the `ls -al` command:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("ls -al", shell=True) # works
subprocess.call("ls -al") # fails
```

Also note the answer of @ibi0tux regarding `exit`